# Output Feature Class empty after trying to display it on map using arcpy.mapping?

Tags: arcpy, export, feature-layer

I am trying display the output of my script on an mxd once it is created.  To do this, i created a function at the end of my class that handles all mapping.  I have tested the code up until the mapping function and it works great.  But when i try to run the script with the mapping function, the output file is empty and so is the layer file i created with it.  Does anything stand out that might edit/save over my output file?

```
def MapOutput(self):
    '''This function Creates a map document, adds the output data, and exports
       a thumbnail of the data.'''
        # Create map document features.
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(self.MapDocument)
        dfs = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
        df = dfs[0]
        # Create a layer file from input data and symbolize it.
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(self.dBaseComparison(), 'Layer')
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management('Layer', self.OutSymb)
        # Add symbolized layer to map document.
        addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer('Layer')
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer)
        # Create a copy of the map document and save it.
        copyName = self.MapDocument[:-4] + "_Output.mxd"
        mxd.saveACopy(copyName)
        del mxd
        # Export a PNG image of the map document.
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(copyName)
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, copyName[:-4] + "_Map.png")
        del mxd
```

Answer (score 1):

`arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management()` doesn't create a layer *file*, it creates an in-memory layer. Adding an in-memory layer to an mxd should not work, you need to save the layer to a layer file with `arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management_management()` afterwards (or alternatively, use a layer already present in the TOC of an mxd):

```
...
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(self.dBaseComparison(), 'Layer')
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management('Layer', self.OutSymb)
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management('Layer', r'C:\folder\lyr.lyr')
...
```